# How to validate a list of ipv4 addresses using flex and bison?

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

The regex which I am using to validate an IPv4 address is as follows:

```
dec_octet   [0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]
IPv4Address {dec_octet}\.{dec_octet}\.{dec_octet}\.{dec_octet}
%%
{IPv4Address}  { /* return the value */ }
```

Now I want to validate a list of ipv4 addresses. It would be good if the same regex can be reused. A Sample input:

```
ip=(1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3)
```

The delimiters can be anything except brackets or commas.
Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `IPV4` is the token lex returns for a valid IPv4 address, add those rules in parser file:

```
ipv4vector:
    "ip" '='  '(' ipv4list ')' 
ipv4list:
    IPV4 | ipv4list ',' IPV4
```